# Solving recurrence finding theta of T(n)=T(log n)+1

Tags: recurrence-relation

$$
T(n)=T(\log n)+1
$$

$$
T(n)=\Theta(...)
$$

I want to find theta of $T(n)$. I tried the master theorem but failed.

Comment: Check [iterated logarithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) $\log^*n$

Comment: thank you,any idea how can i prove it?

Comment: What is your base case for your $T(n)$? Wouldn't the definition of iterated logarithm exactly match your recurrence? You can use induction

Comment: You don't need induction, its the very definition of $\log^*(n)$

Comment: For all practical pursposes, $T(n)\le6$. :-)

Comment: As the comments by Russel and nir shahar point out, there is not much point to answer your question. I recommend you delete your question; or you could post an answer.